# python script for saving subsequent images without overwriting

Tags: python, abaqus

I am new to python but I have been able to make a script (pls see code below and attached picture ) that accesses abaqus .odb output file and saves the contour map as a .tiff file. Since this script runs at interval, the new image file overwrites the previous but I actually want to save the subsequent images with different name e.g. VMises_01, VMises_02, VMises_03, etc.
Please i need asssistance in modifying the script to do this. 
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
# -*- coding: mbcs -*-
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
session.Viewport(name='Viewport: 1', origin=(0.0, 0.0), width=153.191665649414, 
 height=265.695220947266)
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].makeCurrent()
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].maximize()
from caeModules import *![enter image description here][1]
from driverUtils import executeOnCaeStartup
executeOnCaeStartup()
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].partDisplay.geometryOptions.setValues(
 referenceRepresentation=ON)
Mdb()
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=None)
import os
os.chdir(r"C:\Work\2015 CA")
o1 = session.openOdb(name='C:/Work/2015 CA/cafe_del.odb')
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=o1)
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].odbDisplay.display.setValues(plotState=(
 CONTOURS_ON_DEF, ))
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].odbDisplay.commonOptions.setValues(
 visibleEdges=FEATURE, deformationScaling=UNIFORM, uniformScaleFactor=1)
session.printToFile(fileName='C:/Work/2015 CA/VMises_01', format=TIFF, 
 canvasObjects=(session.viewports['Viewport: 1'], ))
session.odbs['C:/Work/2015 CA/cafe_del.odb'].close()
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of getting a unique filename would be to append a timestamp.

e.g. replace

```
session.printToFile(
  fileName='C:/Work/2015 CA/VMises_01', 
  format=TIFF, 
  canvasObjects=(session.viewports['Viewport: 1'], ))
```

with

```
session.printToFile(
  fileName='C:/Work/2015 CA/VMises_%s' % datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%d%m%H%M%S') , 
  format=TIFF, 
  canvasObjects=(session.viewports['Viewport: 1'], ))
```

If instead you want the counter 01, 02, 03, etc, that you proposed, then you'll either need to (a) keep a record of the current number within the script (either in memory or to disk if the script doesn't run continuously), or (b) look at the directory contents to determine the next available number each time.